# How to change position of tooltip arrow

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to reposition the Tooltip arrow on my hover box to the left - at the moment it appears at the top of the box.

Here's my CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
* {
    font-family: Arial;
}

.input {
    position: relative;
}

.tooltip {
    display: none;
    padding: 10px;
}

.input:hover .tooltip {
    background: blue;
    border-radius: 3px;
    bottom: -5px;
    color: white;
    display: inline;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100px;
    left: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    position: absolute;
}

.input:hover .tooltip:before {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 5px solid blue;
}

</style>
```

HTML:

```
<td align="left">
     <tr> 
         <br><br><br><br>
             </tr>
            <div class="input" align="left">
            <input name="amount1" type="text" align="top" class="size-box" id="amount" style="font-size: 14px; width:40px; text-align:center" onclick="this.value = '';" value="0" size="20"><span class="tooltip" style="text-align:center">Deliver Quantity</span></div>
            </td>
```

Could anybody tell me what I'm missing? I can't tell which attribute from the code controls the arrow position...

Thanks.

Comment: Nope, without a fiddle and some html, we're guessing.

Comment: Can you post the HTML as well?

Comment: this could help http://cssarrowplease.com/, although your arrow is on top because of the `top:-5px;` but to move it left you would need to change the borders as well so it pointed in the correct direction

Comment: @Pete - How exactly? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following styles to move the arrow to the left.  I have made the arrow 6px for better centralising as you can't margin -2.5px.

```
.input:hover .tooltip:before {
    display: block;
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top:-3px;
    left: -6px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 6px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 6px solid transparent;
    border-right: 6px solid blue;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/qCPQm/)

Answer (score 0):

just change this class

```
.input:hover .tooltip:before {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: -5px;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-5px;
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid blue;

}
```